# How to create text placeholders in sketchapp?

Tags: overriding, sketchapp

I want to create a navigation trail in sketchapp so I have:

```
section 1 > section 2 > section 3 and so forth.
```

My problem is that I want to be able to have more or less than 3 sections. So that it is possible to just have:

section 1

or

```
section 1 > section 2 > section 3 > section 4
```

Sketchapp does not allow me to leave the text OVERRIDES in blank. Is there a way to have text placeholders?

Answer (score 0):

When I want to create this kind of thing, I just add a space in the text override which make disapear the navigation item I don't want.

Answer (score -1):

You can nest symbols with different number of sections inside of your navigation trail symbol. You would have something like: Parent Symbol > 1 Section symbol or 2 Section symbol or 3 Section symbol or 4 section symbol... And then you can override for the number of sections you want.

[Example of nested symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8MB4.png)

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: That's not a code issue per se, just a shortcut. The user used code as a form to highlight a concept in his question just that. But thanks to point that out.